# How to convert alloy code tot classic titanium

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to use alloy modules (modules written in alloy code) for my classic titanium project, now I saw posts of people saying that you can convert alloy to classic titanium code so that you can use it in your project. The problem is that I don't know how to do that. So if you have a idea on how to covert alloy code to classic titanium code that would be great.

Comment: The alloy modules are common js libraries so they should be able to be converted, I would suggest providing a more specific example of what you are looking to do here.

Comment: I meant modules written in alloy code.

Answer (score 1):

The alloy modules are just regular commonJS modules - you can find them in titanium source code on github.

if you do have an alloy project that you want the source for, all you need to do is run the project and then look inside the build folder of your project - alloy project is just a nice wrapper - which titanium translate to regular titanium code and then compile for you chosen environment.